# PouchDB 400 bad request

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, pouchdb

Hi can you help identify what this pouchDB error means ?

Thanks

controller.js:

```
 pouchDBservice.addToExistingUser(userr._id, 'favoritePro', favPro);
```

services.js:

```
      addToExistingUser = function (docId, key, value) {
            //console.log(docId);
            usersDatabase
                .get(docId)
                .then(function (doc) {
                    doc[key] = value;
                    return usersDatabase.put(doc, docId, doc._rev);
                })
                .then(function () {
                    console.log('added field: ' + key + ' to doc ' + docId);
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    console.log("error from addToExistingUser:");
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
                });

        };
```

I get this error in the console:

```
louisromain.cloudant.com/boardline_users/_bulk_get?revs=true&attachments=true&_nonce=1454421483935:1
POST https://louisromain.cloudant.com/boardline_users/_bulk_get?revs=true&attachments=true&_nonce=1454421483935
400 (Bad Request)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since PouchDB 5.0.0 there is support for `_bulk_get`, which is a new CouchDB API that enables vastly faster replication, set to be debuted in CouchDB 2.0. See [this](https://pouchdb.com/2015/10/06/pouchdb-5.0.0-five-years-of-pouchdb.html) blog post from Nolan Lawson.

It seems that Cloudant does not provide the `_bulk_get` feature, so the error message above is ignorable. Normally PouchDB will output the following message in addition to this error:

> The above 400 is totally normal. PouchDB is just detecting if the
>   remote supports the _bulk_get API.